# How to upload android Apk file to fabric using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-cli, jenkins-pipeline

I built an Android project within Jenkins using Gradle. After a successful build a signed apk file is created. Now I want to upload this signed apk file to fabric with Jenkins.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for late answer but search for fabric beta's jenkins plugin you can simply arrange that sort of upload in post-build actions